# Boot to Fedora USB

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 15.04 installed, and I also made a bootable Fedora USB, using

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/fedora.iso of=/dev/diskname bs=1M
```

but when I attempt to boot, using GRUB menu, it gives me an infinite loading screen with only a small white cursor. How do I make a proper bootable Fedora USB using **dd**?

Comment: Which fedota ISO did you use, and what did you put in place of `diskname`? If you did not download the ISO properly (check the MD5sum/SHA1sum), or the disk specified was not big enough it won't work

Comment: Using dd probably isn't the proper solution in the first place. Please follow Fedora's instructions ([1](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB), [2](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/)). Troubleshooting of Fedora's boot process is not on topic here, even if Ubuntu uses identical components and configuration. This site focuses on Ubuntu users solving problems with Ubuntu, not Ubuntu users asking all kinds of off-topic questions. There is ask.fedoraproject.org and unix.stackexchange.com for Fedora questions.

Comment: I used Fedora 23, for 64 bit, workstation

Comment: Also, I placed it under /dev/sdc, there were 3 other partitions, sdc1,sdc2,and sdc3

Comment: sometimes, dd won't work and you have to do something extra like on older versions of tails

Comment: I have got fedora and ubuntu (and other linux) ISOs to work using `dd` in the past, however I usually better to burn them to a DVD/CD using something like K3B.

Comment: According to https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Burning_ISO_images_to_disc/Making_USB_Media-UNIX_Linux.html#Making_USB_Media-UNIX_Linux-RHEL_Fedora-dd the method in your question should work. This looks like an issue with your BIOS or the boot image, in which case you should report it as a bug on the Fedora bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some iso images are not ready to boot from a usb so dd will not work. Here is what you need to do to make the image bootable.

First, install syslinux:

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

Next, use isohybrid:

```
isohybrid /path/to/fedora.iso --entry 4 --type 0x1c
```

Now, use dd:

```
dd if=/path/to/fedora.iso of=/dev/devicename bs=16M
```

[source](http://web.archive.org/web/20140327085331/https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/linux/index.en.html)